# Is There Pixel Counter for Texture Painting?

Tags: add-on, texture-painting

I was wondering if Blender could count the amount of pixels you paint for texture painting. I looked it up and there didn’t appear to be anything. If there isn’t, it might be a cool add-on idea if it doesn’t already exist...

Comment: What is the purpose for it? Are you needing the overall count of pixels per stroke and adding that up, or are you looking for final output?

Comment: @CraigDJones What I want to happen is for the program to count the total number of pixels I paint on the full texture of the object. I don't know if it's possible, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: I see- so it would be all pixels painted, even those re-painted....